# Flash Collider won´t work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I´m quite new to Flash and currently I´m trying to develop a little game. But my colliders won´t work anymore suddenly. I have to admit, I just coppied the collider part from my professor and i have no idea how they work. 
It worked pretty fine when I inserted "BG" which is the whole background located at the stage. Now i want my character to collide with every platform in the game. 
Well, it worked before. Suddenly it has problems. Why?! :/

The Char_Collider_feet is in my Character_Control
The Platform_Collider is in the BG MovieClip which is located at the stage...

ERROR message: Error 1009 “Null Object Reference Error.”
I know what I means but I can´t find the reason for it especially since it worked in my other project...(well I don´t use document class there)

Main

```
package  
{
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;



public class Main extends MovieClip 
{
public var char:Character_Control;
public var figure:MovieClip;
public var BG:MovieClip;
public var Platform:Platform_Collider;

var allKeys:Object = new Object();
var oCollider;


    public function Main() 
    {
        this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
        this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
        this.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        this.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Gravity);
        Start();
    }



    //Creates Chars and Objects
    public function Start()
    {
        char = new Character_Control(150,450);
        stage.addChild(char);
    }


    //Key pressed
    function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        allKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
    }

    //Key released
    function keyReleased(e:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if(allKeys[e.keyCode] != null)
        allKeys[e.keyCode] = false
        char.stopMove();
    }


    //Sends keyCode to Character_Control
    function update(e:Event)
    {
        //Walk
        if(allKeys[Keyboard.LEFT])
        {char.Move("walk_left");}
        else if(allKeys[Keyboard.RIGHT])
        {char.Move("walk_right");}

        //Jump
        if(allKeys[Keyboard.SPACE])
        {char.Move("jump");}

        //Idle
        char.Move("idle");
    }


    //Tests Collision with Background
    function Gravity(_event:Event)
    {
            //Insert Object which hits "char"
            oCollider = char.hitBGCollider(BG);

            if (oCollider)
            {
                char.Fall(true);
                trace("I collide!");
            }
            else
            {
                char.Fall(false);
                trace("I fall!");
            }
    }


}
}
```

Character_Control

```
package
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.*; 


public class Character_Control extends MovieClip 
{
public var figure:MovieClip;

var speed:int = 5;
var currentSpeed:int = 0;
var jumpPower:int = 5;
var gravity:Number = 0.9;
var isJumping:Boolean = false;
var aCollider:Array = new Array();


    public function Character_Control(posx:Number,posy:Number) 
    {
        this.x = posx;
        this.y = posy;
        this.addEventListener("RegisterCharColliderFeet", RegisterCharColliderFeet); 
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    //Controls Jumps
    public function update(e:Event)
    {
        if(figure.currentAnim=="jumpUP")
        {
            figure.y -=jumpPower;
        }
        else if(figure.currentAnim=="jumpDOWN")
        {
            figure.y +=jumpPower;
        }
    }


    //Moves Character, after Keyboard input received
    public function Move(_action:String)
    {
        switch(_action) 
        { 
            case "walk_left": 
            figure.scaleX = -1;
            currentSpeed = 5;
            figure.x -= currentSpeed*scaleX;
            if(figure.currentAnim=="nothing" || figure.currentAnim=="idle")
            {
                figure.setAnimation("walk");
                isJumping = false;
            }
            break; 

            case "walk_right": 
            figure.scaleX = 1;
            currentSpeed = 5;
            figure.x += currentSpeed*scaleX;
            if(figure.currentAnim=="nothing" || figure.currentAnim=="idle")
            {
                figure.setAnimation("walk");
                isJumping = false;
            }
            break; 

            case "jump": 
            if(!isJumping)
            {
                figure.setAnimation("jump");
                isJumping = true;
            }
            break; 

            case "idle":
            if(figure.currentAnim=="nothing")
            {
                figure.setAnimation("idle");
                isJumping = false;
            }
            break;

            default: 
            figure.setAnimation("idle"); 
            break; 
        }
    }

    //Stopps Move after Key Released
    public function stopMove()
    {
        if (figure.currentAnim=="walk")
        {figure.setAnimation("idle");}
    }




    //For Char_Collider_fett
    public function RegisterCharColliderFeet(_event:Event)
    {
        aCollider.push(_event.target);
        _event.target.visible = false; 
    }



    //Tests Collision with the Object received 
    public function hitBGCollider(_oTest:MovieClip):Char_Collider_feet 
    {
        var posTest:Point = new Point();

        for each (var oCollider:Char_Collider_feet in aCollider)
        {
            posTest.x = oCollider.x;
            posTest.y = oCollider.y;
            posTest = figure.localToGlobal(posTest);
            if (_oTest.hitTestPoint(posTest.x,posTest.y,true))
            {
                return oCollider;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    //Falls every Frame until Collision
    public function Fall(collision:Boolean)
    {
        if (collision)
        {
            gravity *= 1.1;
            figure.y +=2*gravity;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what kind of an engine you're using but it looks like problem is here

```
public var BG:MovieClip;
public var Platform:Platform_Collider;
```

i think that should be like?

```
public var BG:Platform_Collider;
```

so this looks like'll work now

```
char.hitBGCollider(BG);
```

Comment: okay but you have to discuss this question on engine's forum. because i think that's a specific question for your engine. maybe you need something like that?

`public var BG:Platform_Collider = new Platform_Collider(maybe need some parameters here);`

Comment: what do u mean with engine? Flash CS5, action script 3....well the funny thing is it worked with public var BG:MovieClip; but not anymore so i tried different stuff...its works on my other project though...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b56j6689a508d5n/Game.rar i just uploaded the game...maybe this error was to hard to explain, could s.o look into it plz? :/

Comment: what are you doing with this? platfor collider requires x y parameters to be created, haven't you tried anything? why it looks like so empty! i'm not going to spend my time with this stuff... sorry...

Comment: why should it require parameters? i drag and drop it on the stage o.O ive tried for more than 12hours straight how much do i have to try?

Comment: You're going to have much more problems with your knowledge, why aren't you using something like [Flashpunk](http://useflashpunk.net/) to make a game.

Then you can ask all your questions in the forum and can get answers easily.

But in your case here, i can't know what kind of a logic are you using for your game, but if you use a game library, it's better you can find answers quickly and properly because of people now the engine's logic instead of not knowing your logic.